# Does ngClick attach a click handler to every item if put in an ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying about 500+ rows of data in a table and using ngClick on every row to display more info about each row:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="row in displayData.rows track by $index">
          <td><span ng-click="orderDetails(row.orderNumber)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></td><td>{{row.orderNumber}}</td><td>{{row.shiptoCompany}}</td><td>{{row.orderTime}}</td><td>{{row.clientID}}</td><td>{{row.shiptoAttention}}</td><td>{{row.shipMethod}}</td><td>{{row.whenLastShipped}}</td>
        </tr>
```

With vanilla JS I would just put a click handler on the whole table and use the event to figure out what row was clicked. Is there a way to do the same thing with Angular, or is Angular effectively doing that already? I don't want to be attaching 500+ click handlers on the page if that is what I am doing and/or there is a better way to get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a single `ng-click` on the whole table rather than each row http://jsfiddle.net/x2jjdo88/1/

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <table ng-click="tableClick($event)">
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" style="background:#666">
                <td>{{row}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope)
{
   $scope.rows = [1,2,3,4,5];
   $scope.tableClick = function($event)
   {
       var scope = angular.element($event.target).scope();
       console.log(scope.$index);
   };
});
```